# How do I validate the name of the uploaded file in Symfony Forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, file-upload

Here is my input 'terms' in builder from FormUploaderType

```
    ->add('terms', FileType::class, [
        'constraints'   => [
            'pattern'   => '/([a-z]+-)+[20]\d{7}\.pdf/',
            'message'   => 'Change the name of the file',
            'mimeTypes' => [
                "application/pdf",
                "application/x-pdf",
            ],
    ])
```

I want to be sure, that name of the file is exact as I want (for example: 'something-else-in-here-20200430.pdf') but it doesn't work - it shows me an error message...
How do I handle it? I've seen the Annotation method from symfony documentation and also the loadValidatorMetadata method in class entity, but none of them seems to work for me with the file upload...

Comment: Could you provide us this error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the constraints. The `mimeTypes` key corresponds to the [`File`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html) constraint, while `pattern` is for `Regex`.

However, since `terms` is an `UploadedFile`, its `__toString()` method will return the temporary uploaded filename and the check will fail. You'll need to use a [`Callback`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) instead to be able to access the object.

```
->add('terms', FileType::class, [
    'constraints'   => [
        new Callback(function ($object, ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload) {
            $pattern = '/^([a-z]+-)+20\d{6}\.pdf$/';
            if (!preg_match($pattern, $object->getClientOriginalName())) {
                $context->buildViolation('Change the name of the file')
                    ->addViolation();
            }
        }),
        new File([
            'mimeTypes' => [
                "application/pdf",
                "application/x-pdf",
            ],
        ]),
])
```

Comment: I've change the code to yours but how do symfony knows the name of the file? The getClientOriginalName() method is in UploadedFile class that extends File. Should I instantiate this class and import it in my file where I create those constraints?

Comment: @Klekseusz No, a `FileType` in a form is, by definition, an `UploadedFile`. I tried this and works, are you seeing any specific error? If you want IDE completion, then add a `@var` annotation. If your use case is different than "provide an error **on file upload** if the name doesn't conform" then this method won't work, since you *can't* set an initial value to an `input[file]`.

Comment: the phpstorm tells me that Method 'getClientOriginalName'  is not found in my FormUploaderType so I wonder if I should instantiate this File class...

Comment: @Klekseusz Just type-hinting the parameter *should* make everyone happy: `function(UploadedFile $object, ...)`

Comment: the code is working without any errors, but the validation still fails at proper name of the file.

Comment: @Klekseusz I adjusted my regex a bit, either yours or mine could be off, can you [edit] the question to include some actual filenames that you are trying to validate and the current regex you are using?